# Fill rows in between others in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am building a dataframe based on cascading api requests.

First I capture a set of "boxes" (key and title), each box contains a set of groups and each group a set of people.

So the first API call result in a dataframe/array of such:

```
        key                     title
0       ADD                     whatever title
1       ACC                     another title
```

With another API call, I can capture, for each 'key' a set of groups.
I am expecting to construct something like this:

```
        key                     title                              group
0       ADD                     whatever title                     group A
1       ADD                     whatever title                     group B
2       ADD                     whatever title                     group C
3       ACC                     another title                      group D
4       ACC                     another title                      group E
```

And finally each group contains people (I want to get their name and email attribute) so in the end to construct something like this.

```
        key    title              group      person name    person email
0       ADD    whatever title     group A    john           john@x.com
1       ADD    whatever title     group A    alice          alice@y.com
2       ADD    whatever title     group A    bob            bob@z.com
3       ADD    whatever title     group B    josephine      josephine@mail.com
4       ADD    whatever title     group B    alex           alex@mail.com
5       ADD    whatever title     group C    alfred         alfred@mail.com
6       ADD    whatever title     group C    david          david@mail.com
7       ACC    another title      group D    ...            ...
...     ACC    another title      group E    ...            ...
```

Basically the dataframe needs to grow at each api call that will take place in a for loop.
Step 1, I am able to extract an array of groups for example for each row of the first version of the dataframe.

```
for key in dataframe['key']:
    groups.append(<the group>)
```

Which will make the group array to be something like ['group A', 'group B']

But how to insert it within the dataframe to get the structure I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you get `df1`, `df2`, `df3` from your first, second, and third API call respectively, you can merge them to produce what you want: `df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left').merge(df3, on='group', how='left')`

Comment: if this doesn't work, copy the results of `print(df1.head(10).to_dict('list')`, `print(df2.head(10).to_dict('list')`, and `print(df3.head(10).to_dict('list')` and paste them to your question.